# Issue in Debugging the program on CDT-Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse

I am just trying to debug my first Win32 program with CDT-Eclipse.

I am getting the following errors while debugging the program.
   [New Thread 3256.0x498]
   Cannot access memory at address 0x1
   Cannot access memory at address 0x1
   Cannot access memory at address 0x1

Not facing any problem while building or running....

**Informations:**

OS : Windows Xp 7
 Eclipse Version : Indigo
 Tool Chain : Mingw

Using makefile to build instead of Internal Builder.
 Followed the instructions specified at the below link to build the

Win32 program:

bitvector.net/?p=75
 Also, followed the below link as well to correct the debugging process:
 eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/781309/

The program that i am executing is :

```
 #include
 int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
 LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
 MessageBox(NULL, "Hello world!", "Note", MB_OK);
 return 0;
}
```

Please help me to move on.